# How to align with the input in a bootstrap inline form?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is the link to my Plunker: [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/zNxPEn87BgbkaiQZq0HK?p=preview)

The goal is to align the **Sample Parking Ticket** link with the textbox.

Please note the leading label has no class like `col-xs-1` or something.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bootstrap [horizontal form](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal).

Here is a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/CBCotNWlrceu4ym32vxE?p=preview):

```
<h1>Citation Form</h1>
<form name="citationSearchForm" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="citationNumber" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Citation Number:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="text" name="citationNumber" class="form-control" id="citationNumber" placeholder="#"  required="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>Search</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-3 text-right">
      <a id="lnkSample" href="#">Sample Parking Ticket</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```